# disconnection does not happen

Tags: django

I want to set up the disconnection. I have a page, Page 1, that is only accessible to an authenticated user. When i disconnect I can still access page 1.

And i have anothers questions, How does Django know to execute the logout_user function ? (I have the same question for the login but as it works I didn't ask myself the question ^^).

And why do we indicate a redirection in the return when in the html we already indicate the redirection ?

**appIdentification/views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, ("You Were Logged Out!"))
    return redirect('home')
```

**appIdentification/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/login', views.login_user, name="login"),
    path('', views.logout_user, name="logout"),
]
```

**mainApp/template/mainApp/page1.html**

```
<body>
    <h1> PAGE 1 </h1>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}"> Logout </a>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

**mainApp/views.py**

```
@login_required
def page1(request):
    return render(request, 'mainApp/p1.html', {})
```

**mainApp/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
path('mainApp', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('mainApp', include('appIdentification.urls')),
path('home', views.home, name="home"),
path('p1', views.page1, name="p1"),
```

Comment: you can use decorators. It means user can't access that page when logout

Comment: @Manoj Tolagekar, hello I already set it up with `@login_required` . When i disconnect I can always go to page 1 that means it hasn't trigger disconnected function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your first problem

> *I have a page, Page 1, that is only accessible to an authenticated user. When i disconnect I can still access page 1.*

because you've put wrong url for logout it shoud be

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}"> Logout </a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}"> Logout </a>
```

and for your second question

> *How does Django know to execute the logout_user function ?*

Django use [**MVT**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names) pattern in this basically when you go to some url eg. `/logout/` it calls view mapped to that url eg. `logout_user()` and if your view required any data from model then it gets from your model.

Answer to your last question

> *And why do we indicate a redirection in the return when in the html we already indicate the redirection ?*

becouse it's a [**`Post/Redirect/Get`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) web development design pattern

*When a web form is submitted to a server through an **HTTP POST** request, attempts to refresh the server response can cause the contents of the original **POST** to be resubmitted, possibly causing undesired results, such as a duplicate web purchase. Some browsers mitigate this risk by warning the user that they are about to re-issue a **POST** request.*